# Spy Alert called after expect statement

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I am trying to test a piece of code where alert is popped if you try to use back button of browser.

```
var msg = '';
spyOn(window, 'alert').and.callFake((arg) => {
    msg = 'Alert Was Called';
    console.log("My Alert Was Called");
});

history.back();

expect(msg).toEqual('Alert Was Called');
console.log('After Expect Statement');
```

The test fails with the following error
`Expected '' to equal 'Alert Was Called'.` and the logs are in the following order:

```
LOG: 'After Expect Statement'
LOG: 'My Alert Was Called'
```

Comment: Before expect statement, add "tick();".

Comment: It says ```ReferenceError: tick is not defined in path/to/my/file.js```

Comment: This worked setTimeout(function(){ expect(alert_msg).toEqual('Alert Was Called'); }, 3000); Thanks for pointing in the right direction

Comment: I thought you have used fakeAsync, Glad! I could help.